# Proof of $aH=bH$ or $aH \cap bH=\emptyset$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Prove that if $G$ is a group and $H<G$, then  $aH=bH$ or $aH \cap bH=\emptyset$

I have actually broken down the proof into three parts:

Case $1.$ If both $a,b \in H$, we have $aH=H$ and $bH=H$ $\implies$ $aH=bH$

Case $2.$ Let $a \in H$ and $b \notin H$

We have $aH=H$ and $bH \ne H$ $\implies$ $aH \ne bH$
So we are left to prove $aH, bH$ as Disjoint.

Let $c \in aH \cap bH$

Since $aH=H$ we have $c \in H$

Now since $c \in bH$ we have:
$$c=b(b^{-1}c) \in H$$
Now by axioms of subgroup we have:

$b(b^{-1}c) \in bH$ $\implies$ $b^{-1}c \in H$ $\implies$ $b^{-1}cc^{-1}=b^{-1}\in H$  $\implies b \in H$

Which contradicts $b \notin H$

Thus $aH \cap bH =\phi$

Case $3.$

Let both $a,b \notin H$

If $aH \cap bH=\emptyset$ we are done.

Suppose $aH \cap bH \ne \emptyset$ then we need to prove $aH=bH$

Since $aH \cap bH \ne \emptyset$, $\exists x \in aH \cap bH$

So we have:

$$x=ah_1, \text{where}\:h_1 \in H$$ and
$$x=bh_2, \text{where}\:h_2 \in H$$

I am stuck here to prove $aH=bH$

Comment: $ah_1=bh_2\to a=b(h_2h^{-1}_1)=bh_3\to aH=bh_3H=bH$

Comment: it might be of interest to you to show that the set of cosets of a group forms a partition of said group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose, $aH\cap bH \neq \emptyset$

$x\in aH\cap bH$

Then, $x=a h_1$ and $x=bh_2$ fo some $h_1, h_2 \in H$

Hence, $a^{-1}b=h_1h_2^{-1}\in H$

Implies $aH=bH$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need to do three cases (the cases $1$ and $2$ are equivalent to the case $3$ where either $a=e$ or $b=e$). Hence you only have to show the case $3$.

Let $a,b\in G$ and suppose $aH\neq bH$, then we need to show that $aH\cap bH=\emptyset$.

By contradiction let us assume that there exists some $x\in aH\cap bH$, then there exists $h_a,h_b\in H$ such that $x=ah_a=bh_b$. Then $b^{-1}a=h_bh_a^{-1}\in H$ (this holds since $H$ is a subgroup) and this implies that $b^{-1}aH=H\Rightarrow aH=bH$, which is the contradiction we want.